# SQL: only selecting id's where the most frequent value of a second column is a CERTAIN VALUE (Grouped by id)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in SQL (using postgres) with two columns: videoid , classification

```
videoid | classification
1       |20
1       |24
1       |24
1       |24
1       |24
2       |20
2       |20
2       |20
2       |20
2       |24
2       |24
3       |24
3       |24
```

I am trying to retrieve all videoid's where the most common classification is 24. (The answer should only be videoid 1 and 3)
When i use the query: 
(found from [How to select most frequent value in a column per each id group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146919/how-to-select-most-frequent-value-in-a-column-per-each-id-group))

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (videoid) videoid, most_frequent_species FROM (
  SELECT videoid, classification AS most_frequent_species, count(*) as _count
FROM userviewed
GROUP BY videoid, classification) a
ORDER BY videoid, _count DESC
;
```

I retrieve the result set:

```
videoid     | most_frequent_species
    1       |24
    2       |20
    3       |24
```

But when i try to add a WHERE CLAUSE:

```
WHERE classification = 24
```

i get:

```
videoid| most_frequent_species
1      |24
2      |24
3      |24
```

How do I create a query that would only retrieve

```
videoid | most_frequent_species
1       |24
3       |24
```

Comment: You can wrap the query in a subquery and add `WHERE most_frequent_species = 24`

Comment: Thanks Giorgos it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `distinct on` and then filtering:

```
select *
from (select distinct on (videoid) videoid, category, count(*)
      from userviewed
      group by videoid, category
      order by videoid, count(*) desc
     ) vc
where category = 24;
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon this worked perfectly! Saved me so much time

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `having` clause (essentially a post-group where clause), and the `mode` function:

```
select
    videoid
from
    userviewed
group by
    videoid
having
    mode() within group (order by classification) = 24
```

- [`mode` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE)
- [`having` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html)