# Select N most frequent values of column B for each value of column A

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

With a MySQL table like:

```
id | colA | colB
...| 1    | 13
...| 1    | 13
...| 1    | 12
...| 1    | 12
...| 1    | 11
...| 2    | 78
...| 2    | 78
...| 2    | 78
...| 2    | 13
...| 2    | 13
...| 2    | 9
```

For each value in `colA` I want to find the N most frequent values in `colB`.

Example result for N=2:

```
colA | colB
1    | 13
1    | 12
2    | 78
2    | 13
```

I am able to get all unique combinations of `colA` and `colB` with their frequencies using:

```sql
SELECT colA, colB, COUNT(*) AS freq FROM t GROUP BY colA, colB ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

Example result:

```
colA | colB | freq
1    | 13   | 2
1    | 12   | 2
1    | 11   | 1
2    | 78   | 3
2    | 13   | 2
2    | 9    | 1
```

But I struggle to apply a `LIMIT` for each value in `colA` instead of for the whole table.

This is basically like [How to select most frequent value in a column per each id group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146919/how-to-select-most-frequent-value-in-a-column-per-each-id-group), just for MySQL instead of PostgreSQL.

I am using MariaDB 10.1 at the moment.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Neither `colA` nor `colB` are primary keys.

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions, if you can:

```
SELECT colA, colB, freq
FROM (SELECT colA, colB, COUNT(*) AS freq,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM t
      GROUP BY colA, colB 
     ) ab
WHERE seqnum <= 2;
```

Note that you might want `DENSE_RANK()`, `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` depending on how you want to treat ties.  If there are 5 `colB` values with the two highest ranks, then `DENSE_RANK()` will return all five.

If you want exactly two values, then use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a couple CTEs for this, something like:

```
WITH counts AS (
   SELECT colA, colB, COUNT(*) AS freq FROM t GROUP BY colA, colB ORDER BY freq DESC
), most_freq AS (
   SELECT colA, max(freq) FROM counts GROUP BY colA
)
   SELECT counts.*
     FROM counts
     JOIN most_freq ON (counts.colA = most_freq.colA 
                        AND counts.freq = most_freq.freq);
```